Mongodb aggregation "$project" 1 of 2 fields failing on 2nd field
I have a data set that I am "mapping" into different names. Using Mongodb 7.0.
I am using aggregate
I am at the "$project stage
{ 
    _id: 0,
    "First Name": "Executive First Name",
    "Last Name": "Executive Last Name",
    "Title": { $switch: {
      branches: [
        {
          case: { $ne: [ "$Executive Title", null ] },
          then: "$Executive Title"
        },
      ],
      default: "$Professional Title"
    }}
}

So, my source data has long hairy label names, and my output (destined for a CSV import to another system) has different label names.
The $switch statement is killing me.
When "$Executive Title" exists (and has a value) I get the "$Executive Title" in the "Title" field (label, whatever - I'm still trying to come up to speed on terminology for Mongodb).
When "$Executive Title" does not exist, It should populate the "Title" field with "$Professional Title". Instead, I get NO data and the field "Title" does not exist.
I have switched the 2 source fields ("$Executive Title" and "$Professional Title") and the behavior reverses.
I have tried $cond logic with the exact same results. the first mentioned field works, the second does not.
I have had the second 'case:' statement for "$Professional Title" but it doesn't change the results.
I don't know if $project as a stage doesn't allow a second reference to a different field in an assignment or what???? But the second reference always fails.
Example transformation:
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Executive First Name": "Bob",
    "Executive Last Name": "Crachet",
    "Executive Title": "Boss"
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "Executive First Name": "Mary",
    "Executive Last Name": "Nolan",
    "Professional Title": "DDS"
}

transforms to:
{
    "First Name": "Bob",
    "Last Name": "Crachet",
    "Title": "Boss"
},
{
    "First Name": "Mary",
    "Last Name": "Nolan"
}

I would like the second record of the transformation to have the "Title": "DDS" entry....
I have been searching for hours but can't seem to come up the appropriate phrasing to get an answer.
I am not using db.collection.find. I am using db.collection.aggregation.

Starting from @ray solution, another solution is to use $ifNull directly without switch-case.
An example:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "First Name": "$Executive First Name",
      "Last Name": "$Executive Last Name",
      "Title": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$Executive Title",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              then: "$Executive Title"
            }
          ],
          default: "$Professional Title"
        }
      },
      "Title2": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$Executive Title",
          "$Professional Title"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

I added field Title2 that takes the first (ordered) not null value and return that on project.
MongoDB Playground

Fabulous - I love the shorter version. Thank you so much!

You're welcome, I also prefer this version :)

In the end, I went with the shorter answer represented in "Title2". Reading through the docs, this makes good sense and is a LOT easier to read and parse later.. Still getting used to all the special characters and when to use what regarding: curly braces, square braces, colons and others....."Some days it just doesn't pay to chew through the restraining straps!" - I keep wondering if I should have just stayed with 'jq', but I'm beginning to like this MongoDB thing.

From MongoDB official document, $ne is used for a field that exists. For your case, you can use $ifNull to fallback the non-existent field to a value of null.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "First Name": "Executive First Name",
      "Last Name": "Executive Last Name",
      "Title": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$Executive Title",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              then: "$Executive Title"
            }
          ],
          default: "$Professional Title"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thanks! - that worked - Not sure why mine failed, but glad to finally have a solution.

The problem with the original code is that a field that does not exists also does not equal null, so the branch inside the $switch would be true unless "Executive Title" was explicitly set to null.  Note that the mongo query language has special behavior where ($ne: null} matches both null and non-existent, but the aggregation operators do not.

@Joe - Thanks for the explanation. I had come to that conclusion, but was un-aware of the nuance regarding mongo query language -vs- aggregation operators....So much to learn :)
